# Cannot find test method in JUnit test case

Tags: java, testing, junit, glassfish-3

I am currently developing a program that can execute JUnit test cases on external classes. These external classes are sent in by students and we would like to evaluate them.

I have the following test case

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Task1Test {

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        Task1 t = new Task1();
        int a = 5;
        int b = 11;
        assertEquals("Wrong add result", a+b, t.add(a,b));
    }
}
```

and I compiled it with: 
`$ javac -cp .:../lib/junit/junit-4.11.jar Task1Test.java`

The `Task1` will be a student's class, but for now it is just a sample class with an `add` method that will return a wrong result. The file `Task1.java` is located in the same folder as `Task1Test.java`.

In my program I load the test case class and try to run it with `JUnitCore`:

```
String testsPath = "/path/to/classes";
String junitJar = "/path/to/junit-4.11.jar"
URL taskUrl = new File(testsPath).toURI().toURL();
URL[] urls = new URL[] {taskUrl,junitJar};

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
Class<?> clazz = loader.loadClass(task);

Result res = JUnitCore.runClasses(clazz);

if(!res.wasSuccessful()) {
    for(Failure f : res.getFailures()) {
        System.out.println(f.toString());
    }
}
```

However, it does not work as expected. When I run this code, I get this message:
`initializationError(Task1Test): No runnable methods`

When I look into the loaded class using reflections, I can see that the method `testAdd` has no annotation (i.e. `method.getAnnotation(org.junit.Test.class)` returns `null`).

Does anyone have an idea? Did I forget a compiler switch or anything?

I am using Java `1.7.0_11` and the code is run in an web application on Glassfish 3.1.2.2

**EDIT:**

I can run the test case from command line with:
`$ java -cp .:../../code/lib/junit/junit-4.11.jar:../../code/lib/junit/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Task1Test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2779148/494428)
I did not set a parent class loader, which seems to have caused the trouble. Setting it as it was said in the other answer it now executes the test.