# Why getTypesAnnotatedWith returns classes without annotation

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, reflections

I'm trying to use class annotations in Java, and I have the strange behaviour where `getTypesAnnotatedWith` returns a class on which `getAnnotation` returns `null`.

**Is there some reason `getTypesAnnotatedWith` returns classes without annotation?**

For example, in my project the following piece of code returns (correctly) one of the classes I annotated:

```
new Reflections("my.nice.package")
    .getTypesAnnotatedWith(MyTag.class)
    .iterator().next();
```

However, if I call `getAnnotation` on it, the result is `null`:

```
new Reflections("my.nice.package")
    .getTypesAnnotatedWith(MyTag.class)
    .iterator().next()
    .getAnnotation(MyTag.class));
```

This is the annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface MyTag {
    public String value();
}
```

and, for completeness, this is how I annotate classes:

```
@MyTag("FooBar")
class MyClass {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Your example works fine for me.

Comment: It may be due the fact that I have a more complex scenario, with a dynamically loaded jar called by reflection. I'll investigate

Comment: @Federico Did you figure this out? I am having the same problem. I am loading the classes via the URLClassLoader during the Maven build process. I find all the classes but none of the annotations are actually present.

Comment: @mhradek I think the bug was in a custom classloader that I was using, but I don't remember exactly the details...

Comment: @Federico Thank you for the reply. The answer ended up being to specify the current thread like so: `loader = new URLClassLoader(classUrls, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2779148/226805